# How to reposition icons to bottom of page

Tags: html, css

Edit: I have since found the error, I did not link my CSS properly to my HTML, I will leave this question here in hopes that someone who had a legitimate question about icons finds it helps them.

Problem: I have two icons, one linking my GitHub while the other links my LinkedIn. I am attempting to move these icons to the bottom of my page (which so far is blank) for aesthetic purposes. Unfortunately, it is not working.

What I have tried:

- set position to relative/absolute
- used top-merger
- width
- margin 0;
- used float
- used line-height
- used vertical-alignment
- used height

What I believe the problem is: I think I am not using the correct code for the repositioning of this element.

```css
.fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.fa-github {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.fa-linkedin {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<h1>Test H1</h1>
<p>Test p</p>


<a href="" class="fa fa-github"></a>
<a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
```

Image of icons on page: [image: icons]

Comment: The easiest way to handle this is flexbox. https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your plan is, but the quick&dirty solution is to wrap your icons in a `.footer` and use this code:

```css
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    <a href="" class="fa fa-github"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>    
</div>
```

Comment: Very strange... your solution works on Codepen.io and Repl.it but on VSCode (on my PS) it seems to make no changes to my local preview on Edge. This has me thinking that the solutions I tried implementing earlier may have worked but I wasn't able to see it on my end.

Comment: Maybe the problem is somewhere else.